# Is "Clorlina" a name of a person in Spain or Spanish-speaking regions?

Tags: comida, nombres-propios

Is "Clorlina" a name of a person in Spain or Spanish-speaking regions? Is it a variant of "Caroline" or "Carolina"?

There is an extra virgin olive brand produced in Spain, called "Clorlina"? Its barcode is 8436544133904, and I heard 84* means production in Spain.

[image]

I have searched for "Clorlina" in Bing, with or without "olive oil", but only found it is an olive oil brand being sold in China (for example, [here](https://detail.youzan.com/show/goods?from_source=gbox_seo&alias=3645ud2o14nme)). The link says that the brand was founded by a prestigious company named Aires deJaen, by a noble family named Lopez, in Jaén, Andalucia, Spain.

Internet access from China is very restricted, so I am not sure if I got the necessary information.

Thanks.

Comment: Clorlina is not Spanish.

Answer (score 4):

Me tomé el laburo de consultarle al traductor de Google—tampoco en Occidente se sabe mucho acerca de la marca—y pasó esto:

[image]

Parece que *歌洛琳娜 ['Gē luò lín nà' --> 'Clorlina']* es una (mala) transliteración del nombre Gloria al chino. Podría deberse a la falta de diligencia por encontrar una buena traducción para el nombre de la marca, o bien, ante la falta de creatividad los dueños aprovecharon la no-biyectividad de las traducciones para obtener un nuevo nombre. En mi opinión es bastante desagradable, ¿o soy el único que hace la asociación 'Clorlina ~ cloro'? Como sea, no debemos emitir juicios apresurados. Por mi parte voy a esperar hasta que lo probés y nos contés si es una reproducción fiel y acertada de lo que es la Idea de aceite de oliva.

**En síntesis**: no, no es 'Clorlina' un nombre de persona.

Comment: Thanks. I read your comment under Bing's translation. I will not try it, because I have canceled my order.

Answer (score 4):

歌洛琳娜橄榄油产自西班牙安达卢西亚的哈恩地区

Dice exactamente, “El aceite de oliva Glorena se produce en la región de Jaen de Andalucía, España”.

Glorlina es una mala transliteración de 歌洛琳娜 (Glorena). Glorena si es un nombre de mujer aunque poco común, pero existente en el idioma español. P. Ejem Glorena Castillo, Glorena García…

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Spain and that brand does not exist in Spain. Aires de Jaen is a factory and they sell their own olive oil to China and Japan through their own website, translated to chinese:

[Aires de Jaen Official Website](https://www.airesdejaen.com/zh-hant/)

Comment: Thanks. Is the extra virgin olive oil produced by the factory legitimate?

Comment: By "Aires de Jaen" I say yes. By "Clorlina" is say no. But that is more like a personal impression. Never tasted Aires de Jaen oil by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Un nombre de mujer es *Orlina* por lo que no descartaría que sea una sigla acompañada del nombre, por ejemplo *CLub ORLINA*.

A woman's name is *Orlina*, so I would not rule out that it's an acronym accompanied by the name, for example, *CLub ORLINA*.

> Significado del nombre de niña Orlina:
> • Francés: Oro.

<sub>*Fuente [nombresninas.com](https://www.nombresninas.com/nombre/orlina/)*</sub>